# Misaligned mailchimp text boxes?

Tags: html, css, mailchimp

I've customised the mailchimp on http://medictrader.com/demo/ by adding the following css:

```
.mc-field-group{
    background-color: #FAFAFA; 
    padding: 10px;
}

#mce-email {
    float: left;
    margin:10px;
}

#mce-FNAME{
    margin:10px;
}
```

I'm mostly happy with the result but the First name and email boxes are not aligned! Is there a quick fix to this?

Comment: it's clear that the `margin:10px` is overridden somewhere, otherwise it should work expectedly. In fact I tried using Element Inspector to add the style `margin-top:10px` to the `email` class and it works OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#mce-email` is having a `margin-bottom:10px;`
overriding it will solve the issue.

add `margin-bottom:0px !important` for `#mce-email`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but it didn't seem to make a difference. I've also noticed that one has square corners and the other is more rounded, does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: No. open developer console and inspect the email text box, it's having a bottom margin as i mentioned in the answer. Removing it will fix the issue.